# Warning converting to `int' from `double'

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Hey this is really one of the first things I've ever coded. I was wondering how might I fix this error. I am currently trying to do some research but can't find anything that is helpful in fixing it.

```
#include <iostream>            // needed for Cin and Cout
#include <cmath>
#include <csmath>
using namespace std;

/************************************
*     defines
*************************************/
#define  PI  3.14159

/*************************************
*     function prototype
*************************************/

int main()
{
//surface and volume

float radius; 
float height;
float surfacearea;
float volume;
int pi = 3.14159

//Get the radius
cout << "enter the radius: ";
cin >> (float)radius;

//Get height
cout << "enter height: ";
cin >> height;

//Get the surfacearea
surfacearea = 2(pi*radius^2)+2(pi*radius)* height;
cout << "The surfacearea is: " << surfacearea;

//get volume
volume = (pi*radius)^2*height;
cout << "The volume is: " << volume << endl;





system ("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: a warning is not an error

Comment: `int pi = 3.14159` int cannot store any decimals. It will be rounded to simply 3. Change `int pi` to `double pi`.

Comment: `int pi = 3.14159` is missing a `;` and `3.14159` is not an `int`, hence the warning.

Comment: Side note, `^` doesn't do what you think it does. Use `std::pow`.

Comment: What use is having both the macro `PI` and a local variable `pi`? Surely one  pi would be enough.

Comment: use `double` instead of `float` unless you run out of memory

Comment: @tuple_cat You can never have enough pi.

Comment: @tobi303: It should mostly be treated as such, though.

Comment: Despite its name, `float` is not the default floating-point type in C++. `double` is. Use `double` for floating-point numbers unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: @ChristianHackl sure. Nevertheless it is worth to know the difference

Comment: I wouldn't expect `cin >> (float)radius` to compile. I will have to try it. ... OK, I tried, it didn't compile.

Comment: @tobi303: I think it's refreshing for a beginner to treat warnings like errors! :)

Comment: Rather than using `^`, multiply the value, for example: `(pi * radius * radius)`

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I think MSVC++ has an "extension" that a cast to the same type yields an lvalue

Comment: `surfacearea = 2(pi*radius^2)+2(pi*radius)* height;` C++ does not have implied multiplication. Also, `^` does not mean exponentiation in C++. If some book or tutorial taught you that this was valid and correct C++, burn it. If you just assumed it would work, stop doing that. (Sometimes your assumptions can appear valid even though they're not and this *will* seriously burn you.)

Answer (score 1):

Change `int` to `double` for `pi`, because `pi` is a floating point number, which, as stated in the comments, is C++'s default for floating point numbers. Unless there is a particular reason to use `float`, use `double` for floating-point numbers.

```
double pi = 3.14159;
```

And the warning will go away.

Also, you don't have to cast your input to `float`, simply:

```
cin >> radius;
```

Additionally, at the very least, change `radius^2` to `radius*radius`.

But better yet, avoid `^` altogether and use `std::pow`, an example of which can be [found here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow).

Additionally, you don't need to `#define PI 3.14159` because you never use it, and you try to define `pi` in `main()`.

Comment: Also OP has to change `radius^2` to `radius*radius`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, I didn't even look at the math.

Answer (score 0):

You better declare and initialize local variables right before you need them. For constants like `pi` you better use `const` and proper type. For a proper type C++11 offers you a great tool - `auto`. And ^ does not mean power in C++ you have to use `std::pow()` instead. So your code should look like this:

```
const auto pi = 3.14159;

//Get the radius
auto radius = 0.0;
cout << "enter the radius: ";
cin >> radius;

//Get height
auto height = 0.0;
cout << "enter height: ";
cin >> height;

//Get the surfacearea
auto surfacearea = 2 * pi * pow( radius, 2.0 ) + 2 * pi * radius * height;
cout << "The surfacearea is: " << surfacearea << endl;

//get volume
auto volume = pow( pi*radius, 2.0 ) * height;
cout << "The volume is: " << volume << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, a warning is not an error; if it were a compilation error, then the code would not even compile. However, since it was a warning, that means your code did compile successfully and run, except that it produced a warning about something in your code. Now to the bugs in your code:

Firstly, your declaration for the local variable `pi` is incorrect. `pi` is declared in your code as a variable of data type **int**, short for *integer*. An integer is only a whole number, positive and negative one, but one that is neve more specific than 10^0. Now the problem is that you are trying to store a decimal value in an int variable. While the compiler is able to make a conversion of the decimal value into an int value, you lose the precision of the value; that's because it rounds the value. If you compile this sample code:

```
    int floating = 1.23456789;
    cout << floating << endl;
```

It will output 1 instead of 1.23456789, with the reason being that an int variable cannot store a float or double value; it however can convert this float or double value into an int value by rounding it.

Therfore, you should change your declaration for `pi` to:

```
    double pi = 3.14159; // By the way, you forgot to add a semicolon here
```

---

Another problem: you are using unnecessary typecating in your cin statement for the radius:

```
    cin >> (float)radius;
```

You would need to use casting if you want to change the data type of a variable for a particular operation (you don't change the variable data type; you merely process its value as the data type cast. In your case, it is unrequired, because the `radius` variable is already declared as a data type of float, in the line:

```
    float radius;
```

Therefore, I would recommend you to simply change this cin statement to:

```
    cin >> radius;
```

---

One more thing: the following lines in your code have a problem:

```
    surfacearea = 2(pi*radius^2)+2(pi*radius)* height;

    volume = (pi*radius)^2*height;
```

The "^" symbol does not raise a number to a power; it is called a bitwise XOR operator in c++ and it server the purpose of copying the bit if it is set in one operand but not both. You can find more information about it here: [Bitwise Exclusive OR Operator: ^](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3akey979.aspx)

In c++, if you want to raise a number **x** to a power like 2, then you have to do x * x. Alternatively, you can use the `pow()` function like: `pow(x, 2.0)`. For your code, if we use the x*x method, it would be like:

```
    surfacearea = 2(pi*radius*radius)+2(pi*radius)* height;

    volume = (pi*radius)*(pi*radius)*height;
```

Alternatively, if we use the pow() function, then the code would look like:

```
    surfacearea = 2(pi*pow(radius, 2))+2(pi*radius)* height;

    volume = pow((pi*radius), 2)*height;
```

Fixing these peoblems should get your code to work.